# How do I inspect HTML canvas using Chrome DevTools, Chrome version 106+?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I was looking at how to debug a canvas html element but can't find a guide that is updated.

Many guides talk about enabling "Canvas inspection" but no such tool appears in Chrome.

Is this now located somewhere else?

Is it no longer possible to inspect every call made to the canvas like before?

As shown in this picture:
[image]

Source of the picture: https://web.dev/canvas-inspection/

If this no longer exist is there any other method by using some javascript for example, what's the current way of canvas debugging in chrome? One of the usages in mind is to reverse engineer Figma or similar websites that rely on canvas.

Comment: Firefox had it but it was removed since barely anyone used it: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/deprecated_tools/index.html

Comment: A year later, these docs are still up but they're clearly not correct. This tool doesn't appear to exist anywhere.